# Extract References from pdf - Python

Tags: python, text-extraction

In my python project, I need to extract `REFERENCES` from pdf research papers. I'm using `PyPDF2` to read pdf and extract text from it like this.

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('fileName.pdf','rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageCount = pdfReader.numPages
count = 0
text = ''

while count < pageCount:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()
```

Now this `text` can be in any format and I'm unable to identify any heading from it. I can not use `find('References')` because paper can also contain this word anywhere else. Some papers contain Number before heading like **6 REFERENCES**, so I can add regex for this

> but I'm stuck with papers without any Numeric value before heading.

Here is the pdf I'm currently working on [A non-projective dependency parser](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/A97-1011.pdf)

and this is how, I'm getting its references

```
References Arto Anttila. 1995. How to recognise subjects in English. In Karlsson et al., chapt. 9, pp. 315-358. Dekang Lin. 1996. Evaluation of Principar with the Susanne corpus. In John Carroll, editor, Work- shop on Robust Parsing, pages 54-69, Prague. Jason M. Eisner. 1996. Three new probabilistic models for dependency parsing: An exploration. In The 16th International Conference on Compu- tational Linguistics, pages 340-345. Copenhagen. David G. Hays. 1964. Dependency theory: A formalism and some observations. Language, 40(4):511-525. Hans Jiirgen Heringer. 1993. Dependency syntax - basic ideas and the classical model. In Joachim Jacobs, Arnim von Stechow, Wolfgang Sternefeld, and Thee Venneman, editors, Syntax - An In- ternational Handbook of Contemporary Research, volume 1, chapter 12, pages 298-316. Walter de Gruyter, Berlin - New York. Richard Hudson. 1991. English Word Grammar. Basil Blackwell, Cambridge, MA. Arvi Hurskainen. 1996. Disambiguation of morpho- logical analysis in Bantu languages. In The 16th International Conference on Computational Lin- guistics, pages 568-573. Copenhagen. Time J~rvinen. 1994. Annotating 200 million words: the Bank of English project. In The 15th International Conference on Computational Lin- guistics Proceedings, pages 565-568. Kyoto. Fred Karlsson, Atro Voutilainen, Juha Heikkil~, and Arto Anttila, editors. 1995. Constraint Gram- mar: a language-independent system for parsing unrestricted text, volume 4 of Natural Language Processing. Mouton de Gruyter, Berlin and N.Y. Fred Karlsson. 1990. Constraint grammar as a framework for parsing running text. In Hans Karl- gren, editor, Papers presented to the 13th Interna- tional Conference on Computational Linguistics, volume 3, pages 168-173, Helsinki, Finland. Michael McCord. 1990. Slot grammar: A system for simpler construction of practical natural language grammars. In lq, Studer, editor, Natural Language and Logic: International Scientific Symposium, Lecture Notes in Computer Science, pages 118- 145. Springer, Berlin. Igor A. Mel'~uk. 1987. Dependency Syntax: Theory and Practice. State University of New York Press, Albany. Christer Samuelsson, Pasi Tapanainen, and Atro Voutilainen. 1996. Inducing constraint gram- mars. In Laurent Miclet and Colin de la Higuera, editors, Grammatical Inference: Learning Syntax from Sentences, volume 1147 of Lecture Notes in Artificial Intelligence, pages 146-155, Springer. Daniel Sleator and Davy Temperley. 1991. Parsing English with a link grammar. Technical Report CMU-CS-91-196, Carnegie Mellon University. Pasi Tapanainen and Time J/irvinen. 1994. Syn- tactic analysis of natural language using linguis- tic rules and corpus-based patterns. In The 15th International Conference on Computational Lin- guistics Proceedings, pages 629-634. Kyoto. Pasi Tapanainen. 1996. The Constraint Grammar Parser CG-2. Number 27 in Publications of the Department of General Linguistics, University of Helsinki. Lucien TesniSre. 1959. l~ldments de syntaxe stvuc- turale, l~ditions Klincksieck, Paris. Atro Voutilainen. 1995. Morphological disambigua- tion. In Karlsson et al., chapter 6, pages 165-284. 71
```

How can I parse these Reference string into multiple references as mentioned in pdf? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: you should add PDF which makes problem. Without PDF question is useless.

Comment: Added all the required data...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PDF` is very complex and I'm not specialist but I took source code of [extractText()](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/d7b8d3e0f471530267827511cdffaa2ab48bc1ad/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L2645) to see how it works and using `print('>>>', operator, operands)` I could see what values it found in PDF.

In this document it uses `"Tm"` to move position to new line so changed original code in `extractText()` and I used `"Tm"` to add `\n` and I got text in lines

```
Arto Anttila. 1995. How to recognise subjects in 
English. In Karlsson et al., chapt. 9, pp. 315-358. 
Dekang Lin. 1996. Evaluation of Principar with the 
Susanne corpus. In John Carroll, editor, Work- 
shop on Robust Parsing, pages 54-69, Prague. 
Jason M. Eisner. 1996. Three new probabilistic 
models for dependency parsing: An exploration. 
In The 16th International Conference on Compu- 
tational Linguistics, pages 340-345. Copenhagen. 
David G. Hays. 1964. Dependency theory: A 
formalism and some observations. Language, 
40(4):511-525.
```

Or with `---` between lines

```
---
Arto Anttila. 1995. How to recognise subjects in 
---
English. In Karlsson et al., chapt. 9, pp. 315-358. 
---
Dekang Lin. 1996. Evaluation of Principar with the 
---
Susanne corpus. In John Carroll, editor, Work- 
---
shop on Robust Parsing, pages 54-69, Prague. 
---
Jason M. Eisner. 1996. Three new probabilistic 
---
models for dependency parsing: An exploration. 
---
In The 16th International Conference on Compu- 
---
tational Linguistics, pages 340-345. Copenhagen. 
---
David G. Hays. 1964. Dependency theory: A 
---
formalism and some observations. Language, 
---
40(4):511-525.
```

But it still not so usefull but now code which I used to get this result

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2.pdf import *  # to import function used in origimal `extractText`

# --- functions ---

def myExtractText(self):  
    # code from original `extractText()`
    # https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/d7b8d3e0f471530267827511cdffaa2ab48bc1ad/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L2645
    
    text = u_("")

    content = self["/Contents"].getObject()

    if not isinstance(content, ContentStream):
        content = ContentStream(content, self.pdf)
    
    for operands, operator in content.operations:
        # used only for test to see values in variables
        #print('>>>', operator, operands)

        if operator == b_("Tj"):
            _text = operands[0]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += _text
        elif operator == b_("T*"):
            text += "\n"
        elif operator == b_("'"):
            text += "\n"
            _text = operands[0]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += operands[0]
        elif operator == b_('"'):
            _text = operands[2]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += "\n"
                text += _text
        elif operator == b_("TJ"):
            for i in operands[0]:
                if isinstance(i, TextStringObject):
                    text += i
            text += "\n"

        # new code to add `\n` when text moves to new line
        elif operator == b_("Tm"):
            text += '\n'
            
    return text
    
# --- main ---

pdfFileObj = open('A97-1011.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

text = ''

for page in pdfReader.pages:
    #text += page.extractText()  # original function
    text += myExtractText(page)  # modified function

# get only text after word `References`
pos = text.lower().find('references')
text = text[pos+len('references '):]
    
# print all at once
print(text)

# print line by line
for line in text.split('\n'):
    print(line)
    print('---')
```

After digging it seems `Tm` has also values and there is new postion `x, y` which I used to calculate distance between lines of text and I add `\n` when distance is bigger then some value. I tested different values and from value `17` I got expected result

```
---
Arto Anttila. 1995. How to recognise subjects in English. In Karlsson et al., chapt. 9, pp. 315-358. 
---
Dekang Lin. 1996. Evaluation of Principar with the Susanne corpus. In John Carroll, editor, Work- shop on Robust Parsing, pages 54-69, Prague. 
---
Jason M. Eisner. 1996. Three new probabilistic models for dependency parsing: An exploration. In The 16th International Conference on Compu- tational Linguistics, pages 340-345. Copenhagen. 
---
David G. Hays. 1964. Dependency theory: A formalism and some observations. Language, 40(4):511-525. 
---
```

Here code

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2.pdf import *  # to import function used in origimal `extractText`

# --- functions ---

def myExtractText2(self):
    # original code from `page.extractText()`
    # https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/d7b8d3e0f471530267827511cdffaa2ab48bc1ad/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L2645

    text = u_("")

    content = self["/Contents"].getObject()

    if not isinstance(content, ContentStream):
        content = ContentStream(content, self.pdf)
    
    prev_x = 0
    prev_y = 0
    
    for operands, operator in content.operations:
        # used only for test to see values in variables
        #print('>>>', operator, operands)

        if operator == b_("Tj"):
            _text = operands[0]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += _text
        elif operator == b_("T*"):
            text += "\n"
        elif operator == b_("'"):
            text += "\n"
            _text = operands[0]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += operands[0]
        elif operator == b_('"'):
            _text = operands[2]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += "\n"
                text += _text
        elif operator == b_("TJ"):
            for i in operands[0]:
                if isinstance(i, TextStringObject):
                    text += i
            text += "\n"
            
        elif operator == b_("Tm"):
            x = operands[-2]
            y = operands[-1]

            diff_x = prev_x - x
            diff_y = prev_y - y

            #print('>>>', diff_x, diff_y - y)
            #text += f'| {diff_x}, {diff_y - y} |'
            
            if diff_y > 17 or diff_y < 0:  # (bigger margin) or (move to top in next column)
                text += '\n'
                #text += '\n' # to add empty line between elements
                
            prev_x = x
            prev_y = y
            
    return text
        
# --- main ---
        
pdfFileObj = open('A97-1011.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

text = ''

for page in pdfReader.pages:
    #text += page.extractText()  # original function
    text += myExtractText(page)  # modified function

# get only text after word `References`
pos = text.lower().find('references')
text = text[pos+len('references '):]
    
# print all at once
print(text)

# print line by line
for line in text.split('\n'):
    print(line)
    print('---')
```

---

It works for this PDF but other files may have different structure or different distance between `references` and they may need other changes.

---

**EDIT:**

Little more universal version - it gets second argument

If you run without second argument

```
 text += myExtractText(page)
```

then it works like original `extractText()` and you get all in one string.

If second argument is `True`

```
 text += myExtractText(page, True)
```

then it adds new line after every `Tm` - like in my first version.

If second argument is integer number - ie. `17`

```
 text += myExtractText(page, 17)
```

then it adds new line when distance is bigger then `17` - like in my second version.

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2.pdf import *  # to import function used in origimal `extractText`

# --- functions ---

def myExtractText(self, distance=None):
    # original code from `page.extractText()`
    # https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/d7b8d3e0f471530267827511cdffaa2ab48bc1ad/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L2645

    text = u_("")

    content = self["/Contents"].getObject()

    if not isinstance(content, ContentStream):
        content = ContentStream(content, self.pdf)
    
    prev_x = 0
    prev_y = 0
    
    for operands, operator in content.operations:
        # used only for test to see values in variables
        #print('>>>', operator, operands)

        if operator == b_("Tj"):
            _text = operands[0]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += _text
        elif operator == b_("T*"):
            text += "\n"
        elif operator == b_("'"):
            text += "\n"
            _text = operands[0]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += operands[0]
        elif operator == b_('"'):
            _text = operands[2]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += "\n"
                text += _text
        elif operator == b_("TJ"):
            for i in operands[0]:
                if isinstance(i, TextStringObject):
                    text += i
            text += "\n"
            
        if operator == b_("Tm"):
        
            if distance is True: 
                text += '\n'
                
            elif isinstance(distance, int):
                x = operands[-2]
                y = operands[-1]

                diff_x = prev_x - x
                diff_y = prev_y - y

                #print('>>>', diff_x, diff_y - y)
                #text += f'| {diff_x}, {diff_y - y} |'
                
                if diff_y > distance or diff_y < 0:  # (bigger margin) or (move to top in next column)
                    text += '\n'
                    #text += '\n' # to add empty line between elements
                    
                prev_x = x
                prev_y = y
            
    return text
        
# --- main ---
        
pdfFileObj = open('A97-1011.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

text = ''

for page in pdfReader.pages:
    #text += page.extractText()  # original function
    
    #text += myExtractText(page)        # modified function (works like original version)
    #text += myExtractText(page, True)  # modified function (add `\n` after every `Tm`)
    text += myExtractText(page, 17)  # modified function (add `\n` only if distance is bigger then `17`)   

# get only text after word `References`
pos = text.lower().find('references')
text = text[pos+len('references '):]
    
# print all at once
print(text)

# print line by line
for line in text.split('\n'):
    print(line)
    print('---')
```

---

**BTW:** It can be useful not only for `References` but also for rest of text - It seems it split paragraphs.

Result for beginning of PDF

```
---
A non-projective dependency parser 
---
Pasi Tapanainen and Timo J~irvinen University of Helsinki, Department of General Linguistics Research Unit for Multilingual Language Technology P.O. Box 4, FIN-00014 University of Helsinki, Finland {Pas i. Tapanainen, Timo. Jarvinen}@l ing. Hel s inki. f i 
---
Abstract 
---
We describe a practical parser for unre- stricted dependencies. The parser creates links between words and names the links according to their syntactic functions. We first describe the older Constraint Gram- mar parser where many of the ideas come from. Then we proceed to describe the cen- tral ideas of our new parser. Finally, the parser is evaluated. 
---
1 Introduction 
---
We are concerned with surface-syntactic parsing of running text. Our main goal is to describe syntac- tic analyses of sentences using dependency links that show the he~t-modifier relations between words. In addition, these links have labels that refer to the syntactic function of the modifying word. A simpli- fied example is in Figure 1, where the link between I and see denotes that I is the modifier of see and its syntactic function is that of subject. Similarly, a modifies bird, and it is a determiner. 
---
see bi i ~ d'~b~ bird 
---
Figure 1: Dependencies for sentence I see a bird. 
---
First, in this paper, we explain some central con- cepts of the Constraint Grammar framework from which many of the ideas are derived. Then, we give some linguistic background to the notations we are using, with a brief comparison to other current de- pendency formalisms and systems. New formalism is described briefly, and it is utilised in a small toy grammar to illustrate how the formalism works. Fi- nally, the real parsing system, with a grammar of some 2 500 rules, is evaluated. 
---
64 
---
The parser corresponds to over three man-years of work, which does not include the lexical analyser and the morphological disambiguator, both parts of the existing English Constraint Grammar parser (Karls- son et al., 1995). The parsers can be tested via WWW t . 
---
2 Background 
---
Our work is partly based on the work done with the Constraint Grammar framework that was orig- inally proposed by Fred Karlsson (1990). A de- tMled description of the English Constraint Gram- mar (ENGCG) is in Karlsson et al. (1995). The basic rule types of the Constraint Grammar (Tapanainen, 1996) 2 are REMOVE and SELECT for discarding and se- lecting an alternative reading of a word. Rules also have contextual tests that describe the condition ac- cording to which they may be applied. For example, the rule 
---
```

Comment: You actually saved me.. I was stuck on this issue from past one week.. trying out different methods and libraries..thank you for providing me solution and also showing me another way of solving issues. Thanks a bunch..

Comment: BTW: it can be usefull not only for `References` but also for splitting rest of text - I added example for beginning text in your PDF.

Comment: this only worked for one PDF, I've 50 of them, and none of those worked with this code.. Any idea how can I make a generic function to handle all PDFs? It is almost impossible to check/ update *extractText* function for each PDF. Any guesses?

Comment: PDF is veru complex and it is nightmare when you have to scrape data/text from PDF. There is no universal method. If every references are separated by some distance then you can try to get all distances in references and get the biggest value to split them. But it may need many changes in `extractText` - first it would have to get all distances and later read again and use this distance to separate references. OR it would gives it as list of pairs `(distance, text)` to search the biggest distance and split it.