# Get bibliography list and its count from text - Python

Tags: python, list, bibliography

In my python task, I've to read a PDF paper and get all the references with their count (mentioned in paper). [This is the PDF as example](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/A97-1011.pdf) and it has 18 references and say Ref#1 is mentioned in paper for like 3 times and Ref#2 is referred 1 times so this is how I want;

```
Ref#  Count   Reference 
 1     3      Arto Anttila. 1995. How to recognise subjects in English. In Karlsson et al., chapt. 9, pp. 315-358.
 2      1     Dekang Lin. 1996. Evaluation of Principar with the Susanne corpus. In John arroll, editor, Workshop on Robust Parsing, pages 54-69, Prague
 ...
```

I'm done with Ref # and References in a list, and somehow managed to get lines from text having Reference in them by using this regex:

```
regex = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{1}[a-z\u0000-\u007F]+ \([0-9]{4}\)|\([A-Z]{1}[a-z\u0000-\u007F]+, [0-9]{4}\)|\([A-Z]{1}[a-z\u0000-\u007F]+, [0-9]{4}; [A-Za-z \u0000-\u007F,;]*\)|[A-Z]{1}[a-z\u0000-\u007F]+ \([0-9]{4},[A-Za-z0-9\u0000-\u007F ]*\)|[A-Z]{1}[a-z\u0000-\u007F ]+ [a-z]{2} [a-z]{2}. \([0-9]{4}\)')
```

So when I traverse list of String (Text splitted by sentences) and find by upper regex using this code:

```
for i in range(0, len(lstString)):
    refLine = re.findall(regex, lstString[i])
    if(refLine != [] and refLine [0] != []):
        print(refLine)
```

I get some output like this:

```
    (Karls- son et al., 1995)
    Our work is partly based on the work done with the Constraint Grammar framework that was orig- inally proposed by Fred Karlsson
(1990)
    (Tapanainen, 1996)
    (Tapanainen, 1996) is dif- ferent from the former (Karlsson et al., 1995)
    Hurskainen (1996)
    In essence, the same formalism is used in the syn- tactic analysis in J~rvinen (1994) and     Anttila (1995)
    Our notation follows the classical model of depen- dency theory (Heringer, 1993) introduced by Lucien Tesni~re (1959) and later
advocated by Igor Mel'~uk (1987)
    Hudson (1991)
    (Hays, 1964)
    (McCord, 1990; Sleator and Tem- perley, 1991; Eisner, 1996)
    (Hudson, 1991)
    (J~irvinen, 1994)
    The CG-2 program (Tapanainen, 1996) runs a mod- ified disambiguation grammar of Voutilainen (1995)
    (J~rvinen, 1994; Tapanainen and J/~rvinen, 1994)
    (Eisner, 1996)
    Dekang Lin (1996)
    Acknowledgments We are using Atro Voutilainen's (1995)
```

It returns me all strings having References in them but I got some issues like

> 1. It is not capturing Reference like this **Karlsson et al. (1995)**
> 2. Some of these contains 2 reference in them
> 3. How can I update count for each reference in reference list

I tried this code to get count for each ref but it always returns the whole list;

```
matching = [s for s in lstRef if any(xs in s for xs in refLine)]
```

Any Kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which module are you using to read the `pdf`?

Comment: @CONvid19 OP uses `PyPDF2`. You can see some code in previous question [Extract References from pdf - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365767/extract-references-from-pdf-python)

Comment: you could add some code so people could run it and change it - many solution will need totally different solution then you expect (like in previous question) And you could add link to previous question.

Comment: BTW: instead of `for i in range(0, len(lstString)): ... findall(..., lstString[i])` you can do `for text in lstString: ... findall(..., text)`

Comment: BTW: instead of `if (refLine != [] and refLine [0] != []):` you can do `if refLine and refLine[0]:`

Comment: if I put regex in `\( \)` then it gives me only matching part instead of full sentences. But `regex` (as default) is `"grezzy"` and sometimes it matches longer text then you may need.

Comment: it seems some part of regex is repeating in `item ... | item ... | item ...` and maybe you could write it as `item (... | ... | ...)`

Comment: I'm wondering maybe you should do it in different way - get names from references and search these names in all text (except references)

Comment: it is not only names..but also the year that is important.. and it is another task to extract name and year from references..

Comment: it easy to get names and year from `References` which are at the end of document - regex similar to `(.*)\. (\d{4})\.` and you get all names as first string and year as second string. And after that you can use `regex` to split string with names into separated names and later use `split(" ")[-1]` to get surname/lastname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wondering what if to get names (and years) from `References` at the end of document and use them to search references in document.

In previous question you get code which gets `References` at the end of document.

Using regex `'((.*)\. (\d{4})\.` I can get names as one string, year as one string (and eventually both in one string)

```
    authors_and_year = re.match('((.*)\. (\d{4})\.)', line)
    text, authors, year = authors_and_year.groups()
```

ie.

```
   text: Christer Samuelsson, Pasi Tapanainen, and Atro Voutilainen. 1996.
authors: Christer Samuelsson, Pasi Tapanainen, and Atro Voutilainen
   year: 1996
```

Using next regex `',[ ]*and |,[ ]*| and '` I can split string with names into list of names

```
    names = re.split(',[ ]*and |,[ ]*| and ', authors)
```

and using normal `split(" ")` I can get surnames (last names) which can be more useful then full name

```
    names = [(name, name.split(' ')[-1]) for name in names]
```

ie.

```
names: [('Christer Samuelsson', 'Samuelsson'), ('Pasi Tapanainen', 'Tapanainen'), ('Atro Voutilainen', 'Voutilainen')]
```

And now I can use these names (or rather surnames) and years to generate strings like `surname (year)`, `surname, year` and search then in document.

If there are many surnames then I can get first surname adn generate `surname et al. (year)`, etc.

And using these string and starndard string function `text.count(generated_string)` I can count them.

At this moment it is all what I have but It is still not ideal.

You could find all references in document manually and use them to test code. And you would see which one are correctly counted and which needs more changes.

For example there is reference with `'s` in text `We are using Atro Voutilainen's (1995)`. Maybe document should be cleaned like in `NLP` (Natural Language Processing) using [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/)

And some native chars make problem - name `Järvinen` in one place is extracted as `J~rvinen` and in other place as `J/irvinen`

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2.pdf import *  # to import function used in origimal `extractText`

# --- functions ---

def myExtractText(self, distance=None):
    # original code from `page.extractText()`
    # https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/d7b8d3e0f471530267827511cdffaa2ab48bc1ad/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L2645
    
    text = u_("")

    content = self["/Contents"].getObject()

    if not isinstance(content, ContentStream):
        content = ContentStream(content, self.pdf)
    
    prev_x = 0
    prev_y = 0
    
    for operands, operator in content.operations:
        # used only for test to see values in variables
        #print('>>>', operator, operands)

        if operator == b_("Tj"):
            _text = operands[0]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += _text
        elif operator == b_("T*"):
            text += "\n"
        elif operator == b_("'"):
            text += "\n"
            _text = operands[0]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += operands[0]
        elif operator == b_('"'):
            _text = operands[2]
            if isinstance(_text, TextStringObject):
                text += "\n"
                text += _text
        elif operator == b_("TJ"):
            for i in operands[0]:
                if isinstance(i, TextStringObject):
                    text += i
            text += "\n"
            
        if operator == b_("Tm"):
        
            if distance is True: 
                text += '\n'
                
            elif isinstance(distance, int):
                x = operands[-2]
                y = operands[-1]

                diff_x = prev_x - x
                diff_y = prev_y - y

                #print('>>>', diff_x, diff_y - y)
                #text += f'| {diff_x}, {diff_y - y} |'
                
                if diff_y > distance or diff_y < 0:  # (bigger margin) or (move to top in next column)
                    text += '\n'
                    #text += '\n' # to add empty line between elements
                    
                prev_x = x
                prev_y = y
            
    return text
        
# --- main ---
        
pdfFileObj = open('A97-1011.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

text = ''

for page in pdfReader.pages:
    #text += page.extractText()  # original function
    #text += myExtractText(page)        # modified function (works like original version)
    #text += myExtractText(page, True)  # modified function (add `\n` after every `Tm`)
    text += myExtractText(page, 17)  # modified function (add `\n` only if distance is bigger then `17`)   

# get only text after word `References`
pos = text.lower().find('references')

# only referencers as text
references = text[pos+len('references '):]

# doc without references
doc = text[:pos]

# referencers as list
references = references.split('\n')

# remove empty lines and lines which have 2 chars (ie. page number)
references = [item.strip() for item in references if len(item.strip()) > 2]

print('\n--- names ---\n')

data = []

for nubmer, line in enumerate(references, 1): # skip last element with page number
    line = line.strip()
    if line:  # skip empty line
    
        authors_and_year = re.match('((.*)\. (\d{4})\.)', line)
        text, authors, year = authors_and_year.groups()
        #print(text, '|', authors, '|', year)
        
        names = re.split(',[ ]*and |,[ ]*| and ', authors)
        #print(names)
        
        # [(name, last_name), ...]
        names = [(name, name.split(' ')[-1]) for name in names]
        #print(names)
        
        #print(' line:', line)
        print('   text:', text)
        print('authors:', authors)
        print('   year:', year)
        print('  names:', names)
        print('---')
        data.append((authors, names, year))

print('\n--- counting ---\n')

# https://guides.lib.monash.edu/citing-referencing/APA-In-text
# Tapanainen and J/~rvine, 

for authors, names, year in data:
    print('authors:', authors)
    print('   year:', year)
    print('  names:', names)
    print(' et al.:', len(names) > 1)
    print('   and :', len(names) == 2)
    print('---')
    first_lastname = names[0][-1]
    print(doc.count(first_lastname), first_lastname)
    print(doc.count(first_lastname + ', ' + year), first_lastname + ', ' + year)
    print(doc.count(first_lastname + ' (' + year + ')'), first_lastname + ' (' + year + ')')
    
    if len(names) > 1:
        first_lastname_et_al = first_lastname + ' et al.'
        print(doc.count(first_lastname_et_al), first_lastname_et_al)
        print(doc.count(first_lastname_et_al + ', ' + year), first_lastname_et_al + ', ' + year)
        print(doc.count(first_lastname_et_al + ' (' + year + ')'), first_lastname_et_al + ' (' + year + ')')

    if len(names) == 2:
        all_lastnames = ' and '.join(item[-1] for item in names)
        print(doc.count(all_lastnames), all_lastnames)
        print(doc.count(all_lastnames + ', ' + year), all_lastnames + ', ' + year)
        print(doc.count(all_lastnames + ' (' + year + ')'), all_lastnames + ' (' + year + ')')

    print('----------')
```

Result for names extracting:

```
--- names ---

   text: Arto Anttila. 1995.
authors: Arto Anttila
   year: 1995
  names: [('Arto Anttila', 'Anttila')]
---
   text: Dekang Lin. 1996.
authors: Dekang Lin
   year: 1996
  names: [('Dekang Lin', 'Lin')]
---
   text: Jason M. Eisner. 1996.
authors: Jason M. Eisner
   year: 1996
  names: [('Jason M. Eisner', 'Eisner')]
---
   text: David G. Hays. 1964.
authors: David G. Hays
   year: 1964
  names: [('David G. Hays', 'Hays')]
---
   text: Hans Jiirgen Heringer. 1993.
authors: Hans Jiirgen Heringer
   year: 1993
  names: [('Hans Jiirgen Heringer', 'Heringer')]
---
   text: Richard Hudson. 1991.
authors: Richard Hudson
   year: 1991
  names: [('Richard Hudson', 'Hudson')]
---
   text: Arvi Hurskainen. 1996.
authors: Arvi Hurskainen
   year: 1996
  names: [('Arvi Hurskainen', 'Hurskainen')]
---
   text: Time J~rvinen. 1994.
authors: Time J~rvinen
   year: 1994
  names: [('Time J~rvinen', 'J~rvinen')]
---
   text: Fred Karlsson, Atro Voutilainen, Juha Heikkil~, and Arto Anttila, editors. 1995.
authors: Fred Karlsson, Atro Voutilainen, Juha Heikkil~, and Arto Anttila, editors
   year: 1995
  names: [('Fred Karlsson', 'Karlsson'), ('Atro Voutilainen', 'Voutilainen'), ('Juha Heikkil~', 'Heikkil~'), ('Arto Anttila', 'Anttila'), ('editors', 'editors')]
---
   text: Fred Karlsson. 1990.
authors: Fred Karlsson
   year: 1990
  names: [('Fred Karlsson', 'Karlsson')]
---
   text: Michael McCord. 1990.
authors: Michael McCord
   year: 1990
  names: [('Michael McCord', 'McCord')]
---
   text: Igor A. Mel'~uk. 1987.
authors: Igor A. Mel'~uk
   year: 1987
  names: [("Igor A. Mel'~uk", "Mel'~uk")]
---
   text: Christer Samuelsson, Pasi Tapanainen, and Atro Voutilainen. 1996.
authors: Christer Samuelsson, Pasi Tapanainen, and Atro Voutilainen
   year: 1996
  names: [('Christer Samuelsson', 'Samuelsson'), ('Pasi Tapanainen', 'Tapanainen'), ('Atro Voutilainen', 'Voutilainen')]
---
   text: Daniel Sleator and Davy Temperley. 1991.
authors: Daniel Sleator and Davy Temperley
   year: 1991
  names: [('Daniel Sleator', 'Sleator'), ('Davy Temperley', 'Temperley')]
---
   text: Pasi Tapanainen and Time J/irvinen. 1994.
authors: Pasi Tapanainen and Time J/irvinen
   year: 1994
  names: [('Pasi Tapanainen', 'Tapanainen'), ('Time J/irvinen', 'J/irvinen')]
---
   text: Pasi Tapanainen. 1996.
authors: Pasi Tapanainen
   year: 1996
  names: [('Pasi Tapanainen', 'Tapanainen')]
---
   text: Lucien TesniSre. 1959.
authors: Lucien TesniSre
   year: 1959
  names: [('Lucien TesniSre', 'TesniSre')]
---
   text: Atro Voutilainen. 1995.
authors: Atro Voutilainen
   year: 1995
  names: [('Atro Voutilainen', 'Voutilainen')]
---
```

Result for counting:

```
--- counting ---

authors: Arto Anttila
   year: 1995
  names: [('Arto Anttila', 'Anttila')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
1 Anttila
0 Anttila, 1995
1 Anttila (1995)
----------
authors: Dekang Lin
   year: 1996
  names: [('Dekang Lin', 'Lin')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
4 Lin
0 Lin, 1996
1 Lin (1996)
----------
authors: Jason M. Eisner
   year: 1996
  names: [('Jason M. Eisner', 'Eisner')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
2 Eisner
2 Eisner, 1996
0 Eisner (1996)
----------
authors: David G. Hays
   year: 1964
  names: [('David G. Hays', 'Hays')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
1 Hays
1 Hays, 1964
0 Hays (1964)
----------
authors: Hans Jiirgen Heringer
   year: 1993
  names: [('Hans Jiirgen Heringer', 'Heringer')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
1 Heringer
1 Heringer, 1993
0 Heringer (1993)
----------
authors: Richard Hudson
   year: 1991
  names: [('Richard Hudson', 'Hudson')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
2 Hudson
1 Hudson, 1991
1 Hudson (1991)
----------
authors: Arvi Hurskainen
   year: 1996
  names: [('Arvi Hurskainen', 'Hurskainen')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
1 Hurskainen
0 Hurskainen, 1996
1 Hurskainen (1996)
----------
authors: Time J~rvinen
   year: 1994
  names: [('Time J~rvinen', 'J~rvinen')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
2 J~rvinen
1 J~rvinen, 1994
1 J~rvinen (1994)
----------
authors: Fred Karlsson, Atro Voutilainen, Juha Heikkil~, and Arto Anttila, editors
   year: 1995
  names: [('Fred Karlsson', 'Karlsson'), ('Atro Voutilainen', 'Voutilainen'), ('Juha Heikkil~', 'Heikkil~'), ('Arto Anttila', 'Anttila'), ('editors', 'editors')]
 et al.: True
   and : False
---
3 Karlsson
0 Karlsson, 1995
0 Karlsson (1995)
2 Karlsson et al.
1 Karlsson et al., 1995
1 Karlsson et al. (1995)
----------
authors: Fred Karlsson
   year: 1990
  names: [('Fred Karlsson', 'Karlsson')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
3 Karlsson
0 Karlsson, 1990
1 Karlsson (1990)
----------
authors: Michael McCord
   year: 1990
  names: [('Michael McCord', 'McCord')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
1 McCord
1 McCord, 1990
0 McCord (1990)
----------
authors: Igor A. Mel'~uk
   year: 1987
  names: [("Igor A. Mel'~uk", "Mel'~uk")]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
1 Mel'~uk
0 Mel'~uk, 1987
1 Mel'~uk (1987)
----------
authors: Christer Samuelsson, Pasi Tapanainen, and Atro Voutilainen
   year: 1996
  names: [('Christer Samuelsson', 'Samuelsson'), ('Pasi Tapanainen', 'Tapanainen'), ('Atro Voutilainen', 'Voutilainen')]
 et al.: True
   and : False
---
1 Samuelsson
0 Samuelsson, 1996
0 Samuelsson (1996)
1 Samuelsson et al.
0 Samuelsson et al., 1996
1 Samuelsson et al. (1996)
----------
authors: Daniel Sleator and Davy Temperley
   year: 1991
  names: [('Daniel Sleator', 'Sleator'), ('Davy Temperley', 'Temperley')]
 et al.: True
   and : True
---
1 Sleator
0 Sleator, 1991
0 Sleator (1991)
0 Sleator et al.
0 Sleator et al., 1991
0 Sleator et al. (1991)
0 Sleator and Temperley
0 Sleator and Temperley, 1991
0 Sleator and Temperley (1991)
----------
authors: Pasi Tapanainen and Time J/irvinen
   year: 1994
  names: [('Pasi Tapanainen', 'Tapanainen'), ('Time J/irvinen', 'J/irvinen')]
 et al.: True
   and : True
---
6 Tapanainen
0 Tapanainen, 1994
0 Tapanainen (1994)
0 Tapanainen et al.
0 Tapanainen et al., 1994
0 Tapanainen et al. (1994)
0 Tapanainen and J/irvinen
0 Tapanainen and J/irvinen, 1994
0 Tapanainen and J/irvinen (1994)
----------
authors: Pasi Tapanainen
   year: 1996
  names: [('Pasi Tapanainen', 'Tapanainen')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
6 Tapanainen
3 Tapanainen, 1996
0 Tapanainen (1996)
----------
authors: Lucien TesniSre
   year: 1959
  names: [('Lucien TesniSre', 'TesniSre')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
0 TesniSre
0 TesniSre, 1959
0 TesniSre (1959)
----------
authors: Atro Voutilainen
   year: 1995
  names: [('Atro Voutilainen', 'Voutilainen')]
 et al.: False
   and : False
---
3 Voutilainen
0 Voutilainen, 1995
1 Voutilainen (1995)
----------
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect, but the reason why I am traversing whole document instead of reference list is *I also have to point out the section in which reference is mentioned* Like if total count of a reference is 3, i need division i.e 1 count in intro, 1 count in Related Work Section, 1 count is in Conclusion etc. That's why I am traversing whole text, each line one by one to identify Section as well..

Comment: you can do the same in my code - you can count for every line separatelly.

Comment: and for that I've to traverse whole doc.. (because its not about each line, its about count of each reference in each section )

Comment: you can do the same in my code - first you have to split text into sections and later you can run my code for every section separatelly to count for every separatelly separatelly.

Comment: Accepting it as answer because it actually gave me idea :) Thankyou

Comment: I tried to split text in sections using `myExtractText` and `distance` between sections but it seems they use different distances. I also tried to use font size to split it but I couldn't find in PDF information about font size.

Comment: Yes, every PDF has its own configurations.. I had to traverse whole document to achieve this..

Comment: can you check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62542857/2660342