# Extract each paragraphs from multi page pdf to each excel cell using python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I get only data but not in format.

Extract each paragraph from multi-page pdf to each excel cell using python.

I have 1000's of multipage pdf files, to be extracted 1000's excel file with the format. How to identify the start and end of each paragraph ?

```
    import PyPDF2 as p

    PDFfilename = "abc.pdf"

    pdfread = p.PdfFileReader(open(PDFfilename, "rb"))

    f = open("1.xls", "x")
    i = 0
    while i < pdfread.getNumPages():
          Allinfo = pdfread.getPage(i)
          f.writelines(Allinfo.extractText())
          i = i + 1
      f.close()
```

Comment: PDF is very complex format - ie. it can keep every word or char as separated element with own (x,y) position - and probably there is no good method to recognize paragraph. You may try to calculate distance between words but in every PDF it may use different value.

Comment: see [Extract References from pdf - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365767/extract-references-from-pdf-python/)