# How do I split my text string into sections based on headers of the pdf text using python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, pdfminer

I've still VERY new to python so I still haven't found my way around the language well yet.

I'm trying to extract text from PDFs of research articles and separate them by headers into a pandas dataframe.

The headers are standard (abstract, introduction, methods, results, discussion, references), and all a I want is three columns: 1) file name 2) abstract 3) text with "text" being everything between abstract and references (so I want the string of text that's the introduction through the end of the discussion in one group).

I started with this code:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
pdf_dir = "C:/Users/dmari/Documents/Python/HeteroTA/"
pdf_files = glob.glob("%s/*.pdf" % pdf_dir)

output_data = pd.DataFrame(index = [0], columns = ['FileName','Text'])
fileIndex = 0

for file in pdf_files:

  #pdfFileObj = open(file,'rb')     
  cleanText = extract_text(file) 

  
  text = cleanText.split()
  newRow = pd.DataFrame(index = [0], columns = ['FileName','Text'])  
  newRow.iloc[0]['FileName'] = file
  newRow.iloc[0]['Text'] = text
  output_data = pd.concat([output_data, newRow], ignore_index=True)
```

to get an ouput that looks like this:

[image: this]

I want to split up that text even further, but can't seem to find any code online that fits what I need. I tried to use this code:

```
# Create a list with all the strings 
movie_data = ["Name: The_Godfather Year: 1972 Rating: 9.2", 
            "Name: Bird_Box Year: 2018 Rating: 6.8", 
            "Name: Fight_Club Year: 1999 Rating: 8.8"] 
  
# Create a dictionary with the required columns  
# Used later to convert to DataFrame 
movies = {"Name":[], "Year":[], "Rating":[]} 
  
for item in movie_data: 
      
    # For Name field 
    name_field = re.search("Name: .*",item) 
      
    if name_field is not None: 
        name = re.search('\w*\s\w*',name_field.group()) 
    else: 
        name = None
    movies["Name"].append(name.group()) 
      
    # For Year field 
    year_field = re.search("Year: .*",item) 
    if year_field is not None: 
        year = re.search('\s\d\d\d\d',year_field.group()) 
    else: 
        year = None
    movies["Year"].append(year.group().strip()) 
      
    # For rating field 
    rating_field = re.search("Rating: .*",item) 
    if rating_field is not None:  
        rating = re.search('\s\d.\d',rating_field.group()) 
    else:  
        rating - None
    movies["Rating"].append(rating.group().strip()) 
  
# Creating DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(movies) 
print(df)
```

subbing out the example of movie data for my files but couldn't get it to return any output.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your strings always are in that order you could split those strings in your list with `re.split` using `\s*\w+:\s*` as a pattern for example.

Comment: Could you show me an example code using that? I've never used regex before (or much of python) so I'm not sure how it's supposed to look.

Comment: Python is not my forte but I'll see what I can come up with to get you an idea of how you *could* approach the issue =)

Comment: Thank you, JvdV!! I truly appreciate it!

Comment: PDF is complex format and it is hard to recognize parts - it may have every word as separated item with own `x,y` and then it is hard to say which word belong to header and which to content. In one question I tried to use distance `y` to recognize bigger disance between lines which can means header. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365767/extract-references-from-pdf-python/

Comment: Thanks, furas. I'm still having troubles getting it to work, but I think you've pointed me in a better direction.